# Error in complete.cases(object) : invalid 'type' (language) of argument

Tags: r, panel

I try to run pedroni99m cointegration function for panel data in R:

```
pdata=pdata.frame(Data, index = c("t","ID"))
pedroni99m((pdata$logC~pdata$logW+pdata$logR), type.stat = 1, ka = 2)
```

I get this error message:

> Error in complete.cases(object) : invalid 'type' (language) of argument.

my panel data is a pseries 240 obs of 58 variables.

I don't know what to do... can somebody help plz.